# When adding a checkbox to a datagridview datatable I get dataerrors

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview that I've added a checkbox column to. When I preview my data without the checkbox it works fine. when I run the program and try to load the datatable, I get a data error. I'm not sure what may be causing this. Where can I look to figure out what's causing this error?

Thank you

Doug

Comment: What does the data error say exactly? Also, you are likely to get more responses if you accept some of the answers the the questions you've asked.

Comment: I added the following code to my page to try to get the error:   Dim msg = String.Format("DataError occurred:\{0}\{1}\DataErrorContext: {2}", e.Exception.GetType().ToString(), e.Exception.Message, e.Context)
        MessageBox.Show(msg) and I get the error of DataErrorContext: Format, Display

Comment: Instead of throwing code into the comments, you should probably edit your question to include this new information, where you can take advantage of the readability-increasing formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your e.Context returns as Display. If you take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewdataerrorcontexts.aspx) you will see for display it says

> A data error occurred when displaying
>   a cell that was populated by a data
>   source. This value indicates that the
>   value from the data source cannot be
>   displayed by the cell, or a mapping
>   that translates the value from the
>   data source to the cell is missing.

In other words the checkbox column in the dgv probably doesn't quite know how to display the information you are giving it.  So, chances are you are telling the checkboxes whether they should be true or false incorrectly.

**Update**: Perhaps, your solution lies with the [TrueValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.truevalue.aspx) and [FalseValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.falsevalue.aspx) properties of [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.aspx). These properties define when a checkbox should be checked or not checked.  If you don't have these set, or if you are trying to set your checkboxes to something other than either of the two values in these properties, you would have problems.

Comment: Yetti, that was it. The datapropertyname had a "default" value in it that needed to be None and not the name. It loads fine now. Thank you.